# How can i change the footer line to dashed line in fancyhdr?

Tags: fancyhdr

I\m looking for solution that i can change the footer line to dashed line in fancyhdr. [image]

I just dont know how can i change the footer line to dashed line, what can i use, please give me a hint or something because I've been standing still for a days.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please edit your question and add a minimal example of what you got so far?

Comment: Hi, [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447326/whats-the-dotted-line-equivalent-of-rule) could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the footer line with the command in your preamble

```
\renewcommand\footrule{\hdashrule{width}{height}{dash}}
```

where the command `\hdashrule` is from the `dashrule` package. You can see the package manual [here](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dashrule/dashrule.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much i really looking for this solution, finally i can move on !